# unserialize() Please specify classes allowed for unserialization in 2nd argument

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, php-7.3

In my Symfony application I have a `User` entity which is serialized. In the `unserialize()` method, I did this:

```php
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        [
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            $this->enabled
        ] = unserialize($serialized);
    }
```

But PhpStorm underlines in red `unserialize($serialized)` with the following message:

> Please specify classes allowed for unserialization in 2nd argument.

I don't know what I'm supposed to use as a second argument. After some research, I saw that we could put this:

```
unserialize($serializeObj, ["allowed_classes" => true]);
```

But I also found this:

```php
unserialize(
    $serializedData,
    ['allowed_classes' => ['Class1', 'Class2']]
);
```

I'm a little confused, I don't know what I should put in my case so that PhpStorm doesn't complain about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are actually serializing an array, and not a class instance, you just need to pass `false` as allowed classes.

```
 public function unserialize($serialized)
{
        [
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
            $this->password,
            $this->enabled
        ] = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
}
```

If you are serializing the whole entity, you need to pass the class you expect to be instantiated from the unserialization

So let's assume the class is `App\Entity\User`,

```
public function unserialize($serialized) {

    $new = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => [ User::class ]]);
    $this->id       = $new->getId();
    $this->$email   = $new->getEmail();
    $this->password = $new->getPassword();
    $this->enabled  = $new->isEnabled();

}
```

I'm assuming you have have getter methods in the entity for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In the serialize () method, I only serialize id, email, password, enabled. So just a few properties that are part of my User entity, not my whole class. Therefore, I imagine that in my case, this is your 1st proposal that I should use